# How to find the Fisher Information for $\overline{Y}$ where $Y_i := X_i+\mu$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

> Let $(X_i)_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d. RVs. Assume that the density $f_X$ is continuously differentiable, $supp(f_X) = \mathbb{R}$ and $xf_X(x) \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. Further assume that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0$ and $\mathbb{V}[X_i] < \infty$ for all $i$. Now consider $Y_i := X_i + \mu$ for all $i$.
>
> Consider $Y_i := X_i+\mu$ for $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\overline{Y} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ be an estimator for $\mu$. Find a lower bound for $\mathbb{V}[\mu]$.

I recognise that the assumptions allow us to use the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound, so we just need to compute the Fisher Information $I(\mu)$ for $\overline{Y}$, so

$$I(\mu) = n \cdot \mathbb{E}\Bigg[ \bigg(\frac{\partial \ \log(f_\overline{Y}(y \mid \mu))}{\partial \ \mu}\bigg)^2\Bigg],$$

but I do not know how what the density function of $\overline{Y}$ is. By the transformation formula I see that $f_Y(y) = f_X(y-\mu)$ , but I do not understand how to go on from here. Could you please give me a hint?